# Use linq to populate Live-Charts SeriesCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, linq, livecharts

How can I populate `SeriesCollection` for **Live-Charts** using `Linq`?

All my data are stored in the database, where I connect with **Entity Framework**, and I would like to first filter my data and then add it to `SeriesCollection` to diplay the chart on my View.

I'm trying to play with the code:

```
        Using entityconn As New PcappConnection()
            Dim config = Mappers.Xy(Of tbl_Metrics_Employee).Y(Function(o) o.TotalElapsed)
            SeriesCollection = New SeriesCollection(config)
            Dim results = (From i In entityconn.tbl_Metrics_Employee Where i.EEID = EEID() AndAlso i.LogDate = Date.Today).ToArray
            PopulateSeries = New StackedRowSeries() With {
                .Values = New ChartValues(Of Double) From {
                results.AsChartValues()}
            }
            SeriesCollection.Add(PopulateSeries)
        End Using
```

Unfortunately, no result. When I use this for **PopulateSeries** I get 'Specified cast is not valid.'. I understand that I need to use Double. I was trying to change `ToArray()` to `FirstOrDefault()` and change .Value to `results.TotalElapsed()` as well, but I get same exception.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any code that you're currently struggling with?

Comment: please see my updated question. I'm trying to do something with it taking examples from the http://lvcharts.net/ (I know this is in vb.net, but the entire app is coded with it so I need to do this in VB.net)

Comment: I built this example mocking a EntityFramework DataBase, it will help you, this was built with 0.6 and it is not updated yet with 0.7 but most features should be the same https://github.com/beto-rodriguez/Live-Charts/wiki/92-Filtered-Data

Comment: @bto.rdz Thank you very much. I know that there were changes, and I've make amendments as I'm using 0.7.3.1 version, but no result (please see my edited question with the code)